# Stop Firefox from spoofing my timezone

Tags: firefox

On first startup Firefox kindly asked if I wanted to spoof my timezone to improve my privacy. It sounded great, but some sites are now harder to use because any time I specify there is adjusted to my fake timezone, which just breaks it. How do I disable this feature? I guess there should be a line in *about:config* for that, but I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: There's an add-on which does that: [Spoof Timezone](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/spoof-timezone/)  - could it be that you used that?

Comment: In `about:config`, did you set `privacy.resistFingerprinting` to `true`?

Comment: @harrymc it was already true (guess it was so because it was turned on in GUI)

Comment: @AndrewMorton no, I don`t use this add-on

Comment: @biryulin04 You could use the extension to present your correct timezone. Or you could set `privacy.resistFingerprinting` to `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrew Morton mentioned in comments, issue can be fixed by disabling *privacy.resistFingerprinting* or using [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/spoof-timezone/) add-on.

Answer (score 2):

**2023 update:** Firefox now includes a setting to override just the timezone spoofing, which allows you to keep the other default `resistFingerprinting` values.

After navigating to `about:config`, enter `privacy.resistFingerprinting.spoofTimezone` and set the value to `false`.

Info found here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1364261#c41

Comment: This does not seem to be working now. I am instead using `privacy.resistFingerprinting.exemptedDomains` (which appears to be new) for sites where the incorrect timezone is really annoying, e.g. webmail.

Answer (score 0):

From What I can tell by testing the only valid solution to this is to set privacy.resistFingerprinting = false.  The answer given by Ed Lucas of setting privacy.resistFingerprinting.spoofTimezone = false doesn't work. The bug comment at Info found here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1364261#c41  appears not to incorporated into FireFox https://phabricator.services.mozilla.com/D168240
(Wanted to put this as a comment but don't have +50 reputation points)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1210162)