# Inaccurate timezone in firefox

Tags: firefox, fedora, time-zone

the timezone of my location is expressed in my system with
`export TZ=America/Mexico_City` (My system is Fedora 37).

The command `date +"%z %Z"` show me `-0600 CST`. That is good because I recently updated the package 'tzdata' with `yum update tzdata`.

But the problem is Firefox (`firefox-106.0.1-1.fc37.x86_64`), when I execute `-(new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60)` (from firefox debuger) it gives me `-5` and it should be `-6`.

And now my messaging web  applications show me inaccurate time which messages are arrive or send with 1 hour of difference. For example: `Jose sent you a message at 2pm`, but it should show `Jose sent you a message at 1pm`.

I reviewed `privacy.resistFingerprinting` from `about:config` but it shows `false`. I used some plugins for firefox to changing timezone, but that makes messaging applications don't working well (Teams and Telegram).

I tried to reinstall firefox with `yum reinstall firefox` but don't worked. I need to use firefox and don't other browser.

Is there some configuration for firefox to update its timezone database like tzdata??
Or, Is there some configuration to synchronize the timezone of system with the timezone of firefox correctly??

I will thanks you in advance if some of you beautiful people can help me.

Comment: Does this help you out?  Looks like Firefox has a mode to present fake timezones, to improve privacy https://superuser.com/questions/1512512/stop-firefox-from-spoofing-my-timezone?rq=1

Comment: @dsolimano - OP states that *I reviewed privacy.resistFingerprinting from about:config* so that won't be it :p

Comment: perhaps you need the **current** release of firefox - i.e. 112.0.2 - failing that, it may look like going backwards, but perhaps the ESR version 102.10esr

Answer (score 0):

My solutión was `yum update firefox`, now I have `firefox-112.0.1-1.fc37.x86_64`, and timezone database of firefox was updated